# copy file from one folder to same folder name batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subdirectory

I have folder in E:\example. In that there are 5 folder as

1111

2222

3333

4444

5555

There is another folder in D:\test. In that there are 5 files as

mu1111.txt

mu2222.txt

mu3333.txt

mu4444.txt

mu5555.txt

filelist.txt

Here there is filelist.txt file which contain all filename.

Here want i want that test folder files are copy to example folder sub directory with their respective number. For example,

mu1111.txt file from test folder is copy to 1111 subdirectory of Example folder.

Here is my code:

IF EXIST filelist.txt (
for /f %%i in (filelist.txt) do copy mu%%i E:\example\%%~ni\%%~ni.txt
) ELSE (
echo filelist.txt missing.
)

i tried but it is showing path error here:  \%%~ni\

How do i resolve it i can't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid substring handling over the file names, as this scenario is simply enough, you can invert the problem. Instead of for each file, move it to the corresponding folder, you can, for each folder, move into it the corresponding file.

```
for /d %%a in ("e:\example\*") do if exist "d:\test\mu%%~na.txt" (
    copy "d:\test\mu%%~na.txt" "%%~fa"
)
```

Comment: @Stephan, You are right, OP asked for copy, changed. But, sorry, i don't understand `move does not work between drives`. It works.